# How to parse a 2D json array

Tags: java, arrays, json, android-studio

Hello I'm new to android studio and I'm currently trying to figure out how to parse this json file: http://stman1.cs.unh.edu:6191/games into a 2d array. I can't seem to figure out a simple way of doing this.

I'm not sure exactly why object types are returned by the JsonObject. I know it can't be converted to an int because it's likely an array of ints but I also can't get that array because it doesn't have a name like the outer array.

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
   try {
      JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("grid");

      for( int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++ ){
          JSONObject num = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
          gridVals[i] = num.getInt();
      }

   } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: please prefer using library like Gson, it will save you a lot of time in future.

I have few example here, please give it a try 
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:4192693+[json]

Comment: Yeah, the built-in JSON objects don't handle 2D arrays very well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example which you can use directly if you are using Gson library.

```
class Response{

    List<List<Integer>> grid= new ArrayList<>();
}

public class ParsingJson {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // data is your json string that you need to provide here 
        Response response = (new Gson()).fromJson(data, Response.class);

        System.out.println(response.grid.size());

        for (List<Integer> integers : response.grid) {
            for (Integer integer : integers) {
                System.out.println(integer);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I have tried reading your json data using [Gson library](https://github.com/google/gson)

Answer (score 1):

You need two `for` loops for 2d array

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONArray internaljsonArray = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < internaljsonArray.length(); j++) {

        JSONObject num = internaljsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
        gridVals[i][j] = Integer.getInteger(num.toString());
    }
}
```

And `gridVals` should be declared at least as

```
Integer gridVals[][]=new Integer[100][100];
```